# How to Get Equivalent parameter to `mkdir -p` for `mount`?

Tags: linux, mount

Condition: `mount` if not mounted; do not give error if mount already done
Command

```
sudo mount /dev/"$PARTITION" /media/"$USER"/"$LABEL"
```

I do not want to receive notifications

```
mount: /dev/sdb is already mounted or /media/masi/MasiWeek busy
```

I could do if/else structure like in the thread [Check if directory mounted with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422947/54964) but I want to know the default way.

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Comment: What if there is something else mounted? You'd need to check what it is anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent for `mount`, and there is no default or standard way to do what you want.  You'll have to write one.

Here's a script fragment that shows one way of doing this:

```sh
dev="/dev/$PARTITION"
mp="/media/$USER/$LABEL"

if [ $(mount | grep -c "^$dev \| $mp ") -eq 0 ] ; then
  sudo mount "$dev" "$mp"
fi
```

This uses `grep -c` to count how many times either the device (`$dev`) or the mount-point (`$mp`) appear in the output of `mount`.

If they don't appear at all, then it's safe to mount the device.

Note the space after `$dev` and the spaces around `$mp` in the grep pattern.  They're **essential** to prevent false matches with similar device names or mount-points.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the output to `/dev/null`.

```
sudo mount /dev/"$PARTITION" /media/"$USER"/"$LABEL" &> /dev/null
```